# Unable to receive AWS Cognito Verification emails to My Gmail Account

Tags: gmail, amazon-cognito, email-verification

I have configured **SES From email address** to my Cognito User Pool. Using the SES Account, I could able to send emails to my Gmail account. If I use the same email address in the user pool. It is not sending emails to my Gmail account and it is working for yopmails.

Is there any way to check the logs for SES in AWS. For sure it is sending emails successfully.
Is there any chance to verify the Gmail logs??

I am thinking there is a problem with Cognito I guess. Can anyone help??